# How can we add a FEATURE module in SPYDER?

Tags: python, module, spyder

I was trying to add a FEATURE module in my spyder Python but I cannot do it. I tried executing the setup.py file which I got from https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder dev here*) You can't install packages from inside Spyder at this moment.

You need to:

1. Download and uncompress the package
2. Open a terminal (`cmd.exe` if you're on Windows) and move to the directory you uncompressed the package.
3. Run this command there

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```